# Cannot read property 'schedule' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular5, web-frontend, ngx-bootstrap

**The desired output is the BsDatePicker** and for some reason is giving me the error: ***Cannot read property 'schedule' of undefined***.
 and also have the warning **BsDatepickerModule is under development,
      BREAKING CHANGES are possible,
      PLEASE, read changelog**

Angular-CLI version 1.7.4, ngx-bootstrap version 3.0.0, Angular 5


This is the code of the html:

`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth" bsDatepicker class="form-control"/>`

This is the code of the app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { CreateEmployeeComponent } from './employee/create-employee/create-employee.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CreateEmployeeComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { CreateEmployeeComponent } from './employee/create-employee/create-employee.component';

const routes: Routes = [
   { path : 'home' , component : HomeComponent},
   { path : 'createEmployee', component : CreateEmployeeComponent},
   { path : '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch : 'full'},
   { path : '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And this is my .angular-cli.json

```
..."testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",...
```

Comment: For some reason the **version 3.0.0 isn't work**, Then I tried with **2.0.5** and It works perfectly!!! But I still want to know the solution to make the BsDatepicker working, there must be  a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the below steps and it will fix the issue:

```
Step 1: npm uninstall ngx-bootstrap

Step 2: npm install ngx-bootstrap@2.0.5 --save 

Step 3: ng serve

Step 4: Add the css file path "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css" in styles array in angular-cli.json file
```

Answer (score 5):

Version 3.0.0 is not stable. Go for latest stable version **2.0.5**

Following steps works.

```
rm -rf node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
```

package.json : `"ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.0"` to `"ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.5"`,

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap
```

Comment: Instead of using rm, you could go `npm uninstall ngx-bootstrap`

Answer (score 2):

I think ngx-bootstrap 3.0.0 isn't stable version. As you can see in their document site. The latest stable version is 2.0.5.
[document site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALjRC.png)
But when you try to install it by command:

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

This command will try to get latest version is 3.0.0.
So, the reason is simple 3.0.0 is not stable version at this time

Comment: This answer would be better if instead of having the command that causes the error you show the command that fixes it i.e., `npm install ngx-bootstrap@2.0.5 --save`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above mentioned solution and that worked fine for me

The following steps:

package.json : "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.0" to "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.5",

npm install ngx-bootstrap

run the server again : ng serve